# How much activity do browsers allow on unload?

Tags: javascript, html, events, browser

I am using a JavaScript to track the activities of users on my page upon unloading that very page. Consider the following simplified dummie-script to simulate what I am doing on unload:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.get("http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
});
```

The image URL in that case serves as a holder for tracking data.

The image is requested in some browsers (e.g. Firefox 3) and isn't loaded in others (e.g. Firefox 6) when *closing the browser window*.

Probably isn't the way it should be done; anyhow I would like to hold on to it as long as I could make a statement on how reliable the unload-event is.

Any experiences on this?

Comment: I think you should chose other ways to track the activity of your user.

Comment: @ComFreek You are right there! For legacy reasons beyond my control I will have to stick for something like this this for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have some experience with that and I would recommend a slightly different approach like this:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    new Image().src = "http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png?timestamp=" 
           + new Date().getTime();
});
```

The challenge is that if you are making an AJAX-call at unload, you should use synchronous mode. With normal async-mode, it may not succeed at all (for instance in Chrome).

But in this case, a trick using image is just as reliable because the communication is one way only. That works for GET but if you need to POST something then sync-mode is the only option.

Comment: Thank you! You are right about the AJAX behaviour, I haven't had that in mind. Anyhow it is not working. Neither in synchronous mode nor with your very snippet above.

Comment: That is strange. It works perfectly when I use it. Could the browser be using some old cached javascript?

Comment: No, but it looks like it might have been the image cache in one case. I will test that now.

Comment: You are correct. I completely forgot the caching issue. I updated the example once more. Maybe it works better now.

Comment: Of course in a real-live-example the URL would be dynamic anyhow. So far your code seems to solve my issue as well. Thanks a lot!